# Why isn't the arrow for the romance span aligned with the words, like all the others in the navbar and how do I fix it (Entire code isn't mine)

Tags: alignment, sidebar

So, the problem is that the arrow that should open the submenu for the Romance span isn't aligned like all the other spans.

I tried changing some of the wrap and align-items, but that didn't work. I should mention that I'm not a professional programmer, and I'm only a student, so excuse poor coding or dumb mistakes. Most of it isn't mine anyway. (Wish I was that good). Please tell me if I need to provide any more info.

Here's the HTML for the entire page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>
      Home page
    </title>
    <script defer src="/JS files/sidebar.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/CSS files/home_style.css">
    <!-- Boxicons CDN Link -->
    <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.7/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>
  
 <body>
  <div class="sidebar close">
    <div class="logo-details">
      <i class='bx bx-tv'></i>
      <span class="logo_name">Anime</span>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav-links">
      <li>
        <a href="/HTML files/home.html">
          <i class='bx bx-home'></i>
          <span class="link_name">Home</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="sub-menu blank">
          <li><a class="link_name" href="/HTML files/home.html">Home</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="icon-link">
            <a href="#">
            <i class='bx bx-target-lock'></i>
            <span class="link_name">Action</span>
          </a>
          <i class='bx bxs-chevron-down arrow' ></i>
        </div>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a class="link_name" href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Chainsaw Man</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Jigoraku</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">One Punch Man</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
            <li>
        <div class="link-icon">
          <a href="#">
          <i class='bx bx-heart'></i>
          <span class="link_name">Romance</span>
        </a>
        <i class='bx bxs-chevron-down arrow' ></i>
        </div>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a class="link_name" href="#">Romance</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Horimiya</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Tokikaku Kawaii</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Kaguya-sama: Love <br> is war</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Your Lie in April</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Toradora</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"></a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="icon-link">
          <a href="#">
            <i class='bx bxs-magic-wand'></i>
            <span class="link_name">Isekai</span>
          </a>
          <i class='bx bxs-chevron-down arrow' ></i>
        </div>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a class="link_name" href="#">Isekai</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Overlord</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">No Game No Life</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Kumo Desu Ga, <br> Nani Ka?</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="icon-link"> 
          <a href="#">
            <i class='bx bx-joystick' ></i>
            <span class="link_name">Sci-Fi</span>
          </a>
          <i class='bx bxs-chevron-down arrow' ></i>
        </div> 
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a class="link_name" href="#">Analytics</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Tengokyu Daimakyou</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Neon Genesis <br> Evangelion</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Assassination Classroom</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="icon-link">  
        <a href="#">
          <i class='bx bx-laugh'></i>
          <span class="link_name">Comedy</span>
        </a>
        <i class='bx bxs-chevron-down arrow' ></i>
        </div>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a class="link_name" href="#">Comedy</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Ya Boy Kongming</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Zom 100: Bucket <br> List of the Dead</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Bocchi the Rock!</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="icon-link">
          <a href="#">
            <i class='bx bx-landscape'></i>
            <span class="link_name">Slice of Life</span>
          </a>
          <i class='bx bxs-chevron-down arrow' ></i>
        </div>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a class="link_name" href="#">Slice of Life</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Oshi no Ko</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Miss Kobayashi's <br> Dragon Maid</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Gokushufudou</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </div>
</ul>
  </div>
  <section class="home-section">
    <div class="home-content">
      <i class='bx bx-menu' ></i>
      <span class="text">What is Anime?</span>
    </div>
  </section>
  
  <div class="one"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here's the CSS:

```
/* Google Fonts Import Link */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap')
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;
}

.sidebar{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 260px;
  background: #11101d;
  z-index: 100;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.sidebar.close{
  width: 78px;
}
.sidebar .logo-details{
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.sidebar .logo-details i{
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  height: 50px;
  min-width: 78px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
}
.sidebar .logo-details .logo_name{
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family:"Roboto", sans-serif;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}
.sidebar.close .logo-details .logo_name{
  transition-delay: 0s;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.sidebar .nav-links{
  height: 100%;
  padding: 30px 0 150px 0;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.sidebar.close .nav-links{
  overflow: visible;
}
.sidebar .nav-links::-webkit-scrollbar{
  display: none;
}
.sidebar .nav-links li{
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
.sidebar .nav-links li:hover{
  background: #1d1b31;
}
.sidebar .nav-links li .icon-link{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.sidebar.close .nav-links li .icon-link{
  display: block
}
.sidebar .nav-links li i{
  height: 50px;
  min-width: 78px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family:"Roboto", sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.sidebar .nav-links li.showMenu i.arrow{
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
.sidebar.close .nav-links i.arrow{
  display: none;
}
.sidebar .nav-links li a{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.sidebar .nav-links li a .link_name{
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family:"Roboto", sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
.sidebar.close .nav-links li a .link_name{
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu{
  padding: 6px 6px 14px 80px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  background: #1d1b31;
  display: none;
}
.sidebar .nav-links li.showMenu .sub-menu{
  display: block;
}
.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu a{
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family:"Roboto", sans-serif;
  padding: 5px 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  opacity: 0.6;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu a:hover{
  opacity: 1;
}
.sidebar.close .nav-links li .sub-menu{
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: -10px;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0;
  opacity: 0;
  display: block;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 0s;
}
.sidebar.close .nav-links li:hover .sub-menu{
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu .link_name{
  display: none;
}
.sidebar.close .nav-links li .sub-menu .link_name{
  font-size: 18px;
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
}
.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu.blank{
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  padding: 3px 20px 6px 16px;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.sidebar .nav-links li:hover .sub-menu.blank{
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.one {
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  background-color: black;
  height: 400px;
}

.sidebar .profile-details{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 260px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: #1d1b31;
  padding: 12px 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.sidebar.close .profile-details{
  background: none;
}
.sidebar.close .profile-details{
  width: 78px;
}
.sidebar .profile-details .profile-content{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.sidebar .profile-details img{
  height: 52px;
  width: 52px;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 16px;
  margin: 0 14px 0 12px;
  background: #1d1b31;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.sidebar.close .profile-details img{
  padding: 10px;
}
.sidebar .profile-details .profile_name,
.sidebar .profile-details .job{
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family:"Roboto", sans-serif;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.sidebar.close .profile-details i,
.sidebar.close .profile-details .profile_name,
.sidebar.close .profile-details .job{
  display: none;
}
.sidebar .profile-details .job{
  font-size: 12px;
}
.home-section{
  position: relative;
  background: #E4E9F7;
  height: 100vh;
  left: 260px;
  width: calc(100% - 260px);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.sidebar.close ~ .home-section{
  left: 78px;
  width: calc(100% - 78px);
}
.home-section .home-content{
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.home-section .home-content .bx-menu,
.home-section .home-content .text{
  color: #11101d;
  font-size: 35px;
}
.home-section .home-content .bx-menu{
  margin: 0 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.home-section .home-content .text{
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family:"Roboto", sans-serif;
}
@media (max-width: 420px) {
  .sidebar.close .nav-links li .sub-menu{
    display: none;
  }
}
```

and the JS:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < arrow.length; i++) {
    arrow[i].addEventListener("click", (e)=>{
   let arrowParent = e.target.parentElement.parentElement;//selecting main parent of arrow
   arrowParent.classList.toggle("showMenu");
    });
  }
  let sidebar = document.querySelector(".sidebar");
  let sidebarBtn = document.querySelector(".bx-menu");
  console.log(sidebarBtn);
  sidebarBtn.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    sidebar.classList.toggle("close");
  });
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kxhvye8s/ I dont see any misalignment here, am I missing something? Otherwise, there might be other CSS that is cascading and affecting you styling? Or some extension? Have you tried a different browser?

Comment: When you click on the 3 lines, it's meant to open the sidebar, and that's where the misalignment is. I don't know why your version of the same code isn't doing that.

Comment: For some reason, the JS isn't doing what it's meant to on that, but it's working on mine.

Comment: I think the JS is incomplete (where does arrow come from?). If you can setup your own jsfiddle to reproduce your issue it would make it a lot easier to help you debug it. Or sharing a more complete example with the missing JS